# A variant of the radical for integers and the abc-conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, abc-conjecture

Define $\mathcal P(n)=\{\{q_1\},\dots,\{q_m\}\}$ where $n=\prod_{i=1}^mq_i$ and all $q_i\in\mathbb P$. Then one can define

$\displaystyle \operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{p\in\bigcup\mathcal P(n)}p$

and also a variant of the radical

$\displaystyle \operatorname{radx}(n)=\prod_{p\in\bigoplus\mathcal P(n)}p,\,$ 
where $\oplus$ stands for symmetric difference.

$\bigoplus\mathcal P(n)=\{q_1\}\oplus\dots\oplus \{q_m\}$

Both $\operatorname{rad}$ and $\operatorname{radx}$ are multiplicative (but not completely multiplicative) and for all $n$ 
$\operatorname{radx}(n)|\operatorname{rad}(n)$.

Conjecture:

> There exist an $\varepsilon>0$ such that there exist
>   infinitely many  $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb Z_+^3$, $a,b,c$ mutually co-prime,
>   such that  $a+b=c$ and $c>\operatorname{radx}(abc)^{1+\varepsilon}$.

That is, I want a proof that there is no corresponding abc-theorem for 
$\operatorname{radx}$.

Comment: I didn't get what is $radx(n)$. And the notation is $rad(n) = \prod_{p | n} p$ (while $n = \prod_{p^k \| n} p^k$)

Comment: @user1952009: don't you agree that the usual radical can be defined as above?

Comment: If you want but the usual notation in number theory is the one I wrote. And I still don't get $radx(n)$

Comment: @user1952009: the definitions are designed to show the similarity. $p\in\{q_1\}\oplus\dots\oplus \{q_m\}\iff p$ occurs an odd number of times among $q_1,\dots,q_m$.

Comment: Ok so $\displaystyle radx(n) = \prod_{p^k \| n, \ \ k \text{ odd}} p $. For example $radx(2^3.3.5^2)= 6$

Comment: what about $2n+1 = m^2$ and $(n+1)^2 - n^2 = m^2$ ?  $radx(abc)  = 1$ and  $n,n+1,2n+1$ are coprimes

Comment: @user1952009: could you please write an answer, a little more detailed? If it's correct I'll accept it.

Comment: It is your job to check if it is correct, and write the details.

Comment: @user1952009: Yes, but I don't get it, yet. $\overset{..}{\smile}$

Comment: The point, Lehs, is that squares have radx equal to 1, but there are lots of examples of two squares adding to a square.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: too easy for an answer then?

Comment: I believe the user is encouraging *you* to understand the situation and post your own answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: pity then, because it was a good answer.

Comment: It will still be a good answer when you post it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: No, I'm waiting for someone who desires 25 + 100 in reputation.

Comment: I wish you the best of luck.